# Problems for link on validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an attachment models that you can add to an asset when you click a link.  On this page to upload the attachment I have this for a back link:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', asset_path(@asset.id)%>
```

however, when it fails a vaidation it gives a big error and will not display.  How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

For those wanting to know the error is this:

> > Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
> >
> > Extracted source (around line #5):

```
3: <%= render 'form' %>
4: 
5: <%= link_to 'Back', asset_path(@asset.id)%>
```

*NOTE:*
This works fine when it passes validations but not when it does not, asset is being built in the new method of the attachment controller by:

```
@asset = Asset.find(params[:asset_id])
@attachment = @asset.attachments.build
```

Comment: Add the error to your question.

Comment: a **big** error should be dreadful

Comment: Looks like @asset is not initialized, how are you creating it?

Comment: @Mauricio Linhares, I have updated it with the error.

Comment: @Brian see the question again, I recently updated it.  Note though that it only occurs on failure not the first click of the link or when it passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in your `create` action you are not setting an `@asset` variable?

If you are calling `render :new`, it doesn't mean that all variables from `new` action are magically initialized.

I think this can help: [The Difference Between render and redirect_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to)

Comment: That would be it, I just go to find out how to set it in the create variable `@asset = Asset.find(params[:asset_id])` returns this error: Couldn't find Asset without an ID

Comment: I added this line in create, this appears to fix it. `@asset = Asset.find_by_id(@attachment.asset_id)`

Answer (score 2):

Your link to should be inside an unless:

```
<% unless @asset.new_record? %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', asset_path(@asset.id)%>
<% end %>
```

If the @asset object was not saved already, the asset_path will fail as id will be nil.

Comment: This still caused it to throw up an exception page.